# Unknown named module

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a dynamic image button, so I pass the path of the image in the "props", but I am receive the error message "Unknown named module".
When I log the props.imageUrl in the chrome console appears `./test.png`. If I change to `const icon = require('./test.png');` works well! What I am doing wrong ?

```
const ImageButton = (props) => {
  console.log(props.imageUrl);
  const icon = require(props.imageUrl);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>
      <Image
        source={icon}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible in React Native because of how the packager works. You have to require images with static string path. If possible set your `imageUrl` property to `require('./test.png')` and then you can do `<Image source={props.imageUrl} />`

Comment: What about a function which returns an Images with a static string path, and the Image component returns is dynamic?